# Meaning - 'I forget you get baptized pretty quickly in this business'

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> He was patient as we reviewed the key points. But in the end, he
>   indicated he would vote against staying the execution. I decided to
>   reiterate what I thought was the petitioner’s strongest argument.
>
> “No,” he said firmly, and thanked me for the call. I apologized for
>   waking him and hung up. It was a fairly gentle exchange, but I was at
>   a loss, equally unsure whether I’d been wrong for pushing, or whether
>   I’d failed in making the case.
>
> The justice came to my desk first thing the next morning. Before I
>   could say anything, he apologized, saying he hoped he hadn’t been too
>   short with me. “**I forget you get baptized pretty quickly in this
>   business**,” he said, shaking his head.
>
> It struck me as a remarkable act of empathy from a man who’d already
>   been plenty patient with a rookie clerk and who had been, it later was
>   clear to me, correct on the merits. But this was par for the course
>   for Justice Stevens: deeply empathetic, and on the law almost always
>   right.
>
> [— DEBORAH N.
>   PEARLSTEIN](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/11/opinion/11stevens.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0),
>   visiting associate professor at the Georgetown University Law Center
>   and clerk from 1999 to 2000

Does this figurative use relate to the idiom a [baptism of fire](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/baptism)? Is Justice Stevens saying: he forgot that law clerks are introduced too soon in the business, and thus may insist and persevere on something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Unless

1 the saying *baptism by fire* is explicitly used,
or
2 an indication of undergoing extreme abuse or hardship is stated or implied,

then

I would say one of the normal meanings of

*baptism*

is meant

That is, it means an 'initiation' or, more to the point, an 'initiatory experience'.

*I forget you get initiated pretty quickly in this business*

And that baptism/initiation is undergone both (a) by ceremony and (b) by experience, and that it is the latter that is meant or stressed.

*I forget you go through an initiatory experience pretty quickly in this business.*

**See [definition 3](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Baptism&submit.x=0&submit.y=0).**